# Enable useful transaction logging in jboss 7.1.x

Tags: java, logging, transactions, jboss7.x, jta

I'm trying to analyse a problem related to some transaction things happening which I don't expect.

For this I just want to see some transaction logs. We're using jBoss AS 7.1.x and CMT.
I already enabled

```
<logger category="com.arjuna.ats" use-parent-handlers="true">
    <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

But this throws so many logs (~100 between begin and commit) that it's nearly impossible to see the (for me) important things (begin, commit, rollback transaction).

As far as I see the relevant class is

```
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction
```

but there are no logs if I put:

```
<logger category="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction" use-parent-handlers="true">
    <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

It is also not possible to deactivate other anoying logs by setting them to ERROR.

- How to configure the logger that it works as expected?
- Is there another good way to see transaction logs?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting

```
<logger category="com.arjuna.ats.jta">
    <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

The reason is that it is not the class or package hierarchy that determines the logging category, although that is often a good idea. But the Arjuna developers explicitly set it to "com.arjuna.ats.jta" for all classes in their JTA package.

I also have set

```
<logger category="com.arjuna">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
```

to get rid of most of the clutter.